# Finding difference of 2 DateTime Objects with different timezones?

Tags: dart

I need to set the `other` object's timezone to match `now` object which has utc timezone.

I'm comparing two datetime objects but the 'difference' value does not match the expected value. Most likely down to the fact that both objects have different Time Zones (Utc & Bst).

```
void main() {
   var now = new DateTime.now().toUtc();
  print(now);
  print(now.timeZoneName);
   var other = DateTime.parse("2020-05-22 18:27:32.608069");  
  print(other);
  print(other.timeZoneName);
   var diff = now.difference(other);
    print(diff);

}

output:
2020-05-22 19:26:39.169Z
UTC
2020-05-22 18:27:32.608
British Summer Time
1:59:06.561000
```

Comment: `now.difference(other.toUtc());`

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. its has an extra 1 hour.

Comment: Are you sure 1:59:06 isn't correct?

Comment: What does `print(other.toUtc());` say?

Comment: now: `2020-05-22 19:59:14.511Z`, other: `2020-05-22 17:27:32.608Z`

Comment: I've explained the probable cause in the post - diff timezones appears to be the issue.

Comment: If the time is 18:27 BST that means it is 17:27 UTC.  That is 2 hours from 19:27 UTC.  This is correct

Comment: For example 2 feet - 1 inch is not 1, it is 23 inches.  You have to convert to the same timezone first, and then subtract.

Comment: @LouFranco right! how do you convert timezones?

Comment: It looks like you want `var other = DateTime.parse("2020-05-22 18:27:32.608069");` to set the date to UTC timezone

Comment: You don't want to convert (that's what `toUtc()`) does

Comment: You want the time to be interpreted at UTC to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to convert, you want to read in a date/time as UTC.

Change

```
var other = DateTime.parse("2020-05-22 18:27:32.608069");
```

to

```
var other = DateTime.parse("2020-05-22 18:27:32.608069z");
```

If other is already constructed, you need to make a new object with `DateTime.utc()`

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.utc.html

```
var newDate = new DateTime.utc(other.year, other.month, other.day, other.hour, other.minute, other.second, other.millisecond, other.microsecond);
```